# IntelliJ Cannot resolve symbol n

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have the following scala code. IntelliJ says "Cannot resolve symbol n". I tried "File | Invalidate " trick but it didn't solve the issue.

```
  abstract class Nat {
    def isZero: Boolean

    def predecessor: Nat

    def successor: Nat = new Succ(this)

    def +(that: Nat): Nat

    def -(that: Nat): Nat
  }

  object Succ (n: Nat) extends Nat {
    def isZero: Boolean = false
    def predecessor: Nat = n
    def +(that: Nat) = new Succ(n + that)
    def -(that: Nat): Nat =  if (that.isZero) this else n - that.predecessor
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have parameters for an `object` Succ. use `class` instead.

```
class Succ (n: Nat) extends Nat {
  def isZero: Boolean = false
  def predecessor: Nat = n
  def +(that: Nat) = new Succ(n + that)
  def -(that: Nat): Nat =  if (that.isZero) this else n - that.predecessor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects in Scala cannot take parameters. This is not valid Scala code. This also applies to traits. If you need to pass constructor parameters then use a class.

Comment: For traits, this will be changing soon ([SIP](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/trait-parameters.html) and [PR in Dotty](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/639)).